# I hope he will succeed vs I hope he succeeds

Tags: meaning

Are there any shades of meaning? I think "I hope he succeeds " has a little higher possibility of his succeeding than "I hope he will succeed" . Or these two sentences are used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4):

They are basically equivalent. The only nuance, to me, would be

> I hope he succeeds

is more immediate (in terms of time)

> John is running in a race this weekend. I hope he succeeds.

as opposed to

> John is trying to qualify for the Olympics. I hope he will succeed.

hoping for success some time in the future (though **I hope he succeeds** can be used here without loss of meaning)

Comment: Does your answer also apply for *"I hope you find what you're looking for"* vs. *"I hope you'll find ..."* as in [this song](https://genius.com/Olivia-obrien-find-what-youre-looking-for-lyrics)?

Comment: Yes, "I hope you **will** find..." has a feeling of a longer search than "I hope you find...", though "I hope you find..." is usually used in everyday language and in the context of your song, I don't think the singer is necessarily hoping it will be a short search, she is just still expressing feelings which she still has.  Most people will use them interchangeably and favor the fewer words for economy.